# ios newly created swift file import cocoa defaultly in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm developing an iOS app and want to build new features in swift now. But when I create a new file by Xcode->File->New->File->Cocoa Class->Language Swift  the newly created file always `import Cocoa` instead of `UIKit`.

Is this the default behavior for all of you? And is there a way to change to import UIKit every time create a new swift file?

UPDATE: thanks for all the answers. I made a terrible mistake

Comment: The UIKit & UIFoundation bydefault imported. So no need to import them

Comment: For iOS projects you should use Xcode->File->New->File->Cocoa Touch Class and not Xcode->File->New->File->Cocoa Class.

If you use Cocoa Class it will import Cocoa and not UIKit

Comment: Import Cocoa is for Mac OS X development and Import UIKit is for iOS development.  As Vivek explains above you need to choose  Xcode->File->New->File->Cocoa Touch Class if you are building an iOS app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ensure that you choose your file from `iOS` section not `OS X` and then it will use `UIKit` instead `Cocoa`

[image: screenshot]